# how to validate the facebook and twitter plugins with html 4.01 strict doctype

Tags: html, facebook, validation, twitter

i use the facebook and twitter plugins in my html 4.01 strict doctype,which give me the following error.

```
Error Line 166, Column 23: there is no attribute "HREF"
Line 166, Column 107: there is no attribute "SHOW_FACES"
```

please help me how i removed these validation error's from my html page.
i use the following doctype and code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

facebook code

```
 <fb:like-box href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/mysite/45662125588" width="692" show_faces="true" stream="true" header="true"></fb:like-box>
```

please help me if you have any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"
      xmlns:google="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0"
      xmlns:twitter="http://api.twitter.com/">
```

Then if that doesn't work, change the DOC type to something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC 
      "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN" 
      "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd">
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it seems that the only way for validator + facebook plugin to work is to use
**HTML5 doctype**

```
<!doctype html>
```